# SpriteKit physicsBody applyImpulse node fails

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to create a jump event on touch screen action, but after applyImpulse my sprite is fails through another(which at the bottom of the screen). With some parameters everything looks good, but sometimes it happen.

Code:

[self.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(dx/mag*kImpuleScale, 20.0f)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put a physicsBody around your Screen simply with:

```
var borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
self.physicsBody = borderBody
```

Then no body can "escape"